# The surface plot is not showing any image in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to plot a 3d surface plot in jupyter notebook but it is not showing any image.

**The code is:**

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,5],'y':[10,20,30,20,10],'z':[500,400,300,200,100]})
df2.iplot(kind='surface')
```

**Output-**
the output image is black in color

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing some libraries or imports. Make sure you have installed `cufflinks`, `matplotlib`, `plotly`, imported and ran before plotting:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly import __version__
%matplotlib inline
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()
```